# Confused about throwing Exceptions in C#

Tags: c#, exception, try-catch

I using `try/catch` and `throw` to handle exceptions. So I am using `try/catch` is used capture errors which include problems like file is not available etc and then using `throw` when the `text` contains wrong values.

The basic layout of my `Main()` is as follows:

```
   while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            try
            {
                //get the input from readLine and saving it

                if (!valuesAreValid)
                {
                    //this doesnt make the code stop running
                    throw new Exception("This value is not wrong"); 

                 } else{
                 //write to file
                 }
            }
            catch (IndexOutOfRangeException)
            {
               //trying to throw the exception here but the code stops

            }

            catch (Exception e)
            {

               //trying to throw the exception here but the code stops 


            }
```

So if you notice I am throwing an exception **inside** `try/catch` and that doesnt stop the program whereas when trying to throw `Exception` inside the catch statement, the code stops. Does anyone have any idea how to fix this?

Comment: You're handling the exception (catching it) and then doing nothing which means it will continue.  If you throw in the catch, there's nothing to catch it.

Comment: if it is your Main() and you want to throw expcetion from the catch block.. where are you planning to handle that thrown exception..? offcourse it will make your app crash

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you throw an exception inside a `catch`, it will not be handled by that `catch`. If there's no `catch` further up, you'll get an unhandled exception.

```
try {
    try {
        throw new Exception("example");
    } catch {
        throw new Exception("caught example, threw new exception");
    }
} catch {
    throw new Exception("caught second exception, throwing third!");
    // the above exception is unhandled, because there's no more catch statements
}
```

Comment: I think this makes sense! let me try that quickly and get back to you sir!

Comment: Oh ok, so what I am doing is, `true or false` if the value is valid so not sure how the `try` statements will work =(

Comment: @User1204501 perhaps you could update your question to explain what you are trying to do.. Perhaps you are using `throw` when some other method would be better.

Comment: no worries I think this will solve the problem =) will accept the answer

Answer (score 2):

By default, unless you rethrow an exception in the catch block, the exception will stop propogating upwards at the 'catch' block where it was caught. Which means, the program will not exit.

If you don't want to catch the exception, and want the program to exit, you have two options:
 - remove the catch block for 'Exception'
 - rethrow the exception inside it's catch block.

```
catch (Exception e)
{
   throw e; // rethrow the exception, else it will stop propogating at this point
}
```

In general, unless you have some logical response to an exception, avoid catching it at all. This way you will not "hide" or suppress errors that should cause the program to error out.

Also, the MSDN documentation is a pretty good place to understand exception handling: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229005%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: Don't do `throw e`, it breaks the stack-trace. Just do `throw`. And of course there's no point in catching if *all* you do is re-throw.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow Nikhil! Congrats on first answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            try
            {
                //get the input from readLine and saving it

                if (!valuesAreValid)
                {
                    //this doesnt make the code stop running
                    throw new Exception("This value is not wrong"); 

                 } else{
                 //write to file
                 }
            }
            catch (IndexOutOfRangeException)
            {
               //trying to throw the exception here but the code stops

            }

            catch (Exception e)
            {

               //trying to throw the exception here but the code stops 
             throw e; 

            }
```

Comment: Hi there, using `throw e;` still stops the code at that line.

Comment: Even though this doesn't answer the question, it's worth noting that you should never catch and rethrow an exception like that.  If you want to rethrow the same exception you just caught, you just write `throw;`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "stop the program".  The program will stop if you do not handle an exception, but your code is handling the Exception you throw via the catch (Exception e) block.
Or maybe you mean that you want to exit the while loop, in which case you could use **break**.

Comment: I guess then the problem is throwing an exception in `try` statement

Comment: @User1204501 The problem is throwing an exception in the `catch` statement.  You can either throw the exception inside the `try` part, or add another `try`/`catch` inside the `catch` part.

Comment: try catch blocks are for handling exceptions.  The catch block can be the most basic of catch (Exception e) which will catch all exceptions, since all exceptions derive from the base type Exception.  You could remove the 2nd catch block and your exception would not be handled.